# Swagger 1.5.3 lists "body" as a param for GET retquests

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Since ugprading to Swagger 1.5.3-M1 from 1.5.3 I noticed our swagger.json file is different (and wrong)

Before a sample get request would look like this.

```
   "paths":{  
      "/stores":{  
         "get":{  
            "tags":[  
               "stores"
            ],
            "summary":"Retrieve a list of stores",
            "description":"",
            "operationId":"getStores",
            "produces":[  
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters":[  
               {  
                  "name":"api_key",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"API consumer key",
                  "required":false,
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"onlyConnectedStores",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"Only select connected stores",
                  "required":false,
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"offset",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"Number of records to offset before returning first record",
                  "required":false,
                  "type":"string",
                  "default":"0"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"limit",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"Number of records to return",
                  "required":false,
                  "type":"string",
                  "default":"10"
               }
            ],
```

Now it looks like this

```
  "paths":{  
      "/stores":{  
         "get":{  
            "tags":[  
               "stores"
            ],
            "summary":"Retrieve a list of stores",
            "description":"",
            "operationId":"getStores",
            "produces":[  
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters":[  
               {  
                  "in":"body",
                  "name":"body",
                  "required":false,
                  "schema":{  
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/AsynchronousResponse"
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "name":"api_key",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"API consumer key",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"onlyConnectedStores",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"Only select connected stores",
                  "required":false,
                  "type":"string",
                  "default":"false"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"offset",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"Number of records to offset before returning first record",
                  "required":false,
                  "type":"string",
                  "default":"0"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"limit",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"Number of records to return",
                  "required":false,
                  "type":"string",
                  "default":"10"
               }
            ],
```

Is because of this it appears to be showing body as a parameter for any of our GET requests when there is in fact no "body" param.

[image]

Any ida why this extra "body" param would be showing up on the lattest swagger release?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this is due to some behavioral change. I assume the method in question has a parameter called `AsynchronousResponse`. It would help if you can open an issue on the project with the method signature, so we may be able to hide the parameter by default.

In the mean time, you can hide it by adding on that method parameter `@ApiParam(hidden=true)`.